# How to make the Distributed-Lock on Database ( mainly on mysql )

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I have already finish dlock by wrapping redisson, and I'm trying to impl it on database, exactly on mysql.

I'm using JdbcTemplate And DataSourceTransactionManager to start a tx, my plans can be show in 3 parts:

1. using `select ... for update` to query the record and lock
2. if the record is not exist, then `insert into values` add a record
3. do bussiness, and finally `delete from where` remove this record and release lock

it work well in single-thread, but when comes to a concurrent enviroment, exceptions occurs:

> org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [ insert into lock1 ( lock_key, holder, created_time, expired_time )  values ( ?, ?, ?, ? ); ]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I realized that there is no need to excute `select ... for update` for `lock()` method, so I removed it and directly using `insert into values` with `try catch`.

But anoter problem occurs, I also had a `tryLock(time, unit)` method, and I'm using `select ... for update skip locked` to do fast-check. However, if record wasn't exist in the begin, it also would be trapped in `deadlock`

So, how to design the distribute lock in database, at least achieve `lock(), unlock(), tryLock(), tryLock(time, unit)`?